# Regex decimal that accepted point and comma

Tags: regex

I have a regex Decimal that accepted only(.) i want to accepted also (,).
that meant the user can enter value 0.1 or 0,1

```
"^[0-9]{1,5}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$"
```

how can I modified this regex to accepted , also

Answer (score 3):

Replace `\.` by `[.,]`. You'll get the following regex

```
^[0-9]{1,5}([.,][0-9]{0,2})?$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a character class:

```
^[0-9]{1,5}([.,][0-9]{0,2})?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the comma and dot inside the character class to handle both `[]`

```
^[0-9]{1,5}([.,][0-9]{0,2})?$
              ^
```

But I am not sure why you are checking `{0,2}` at the end? Which means only it will accept `1111.` as a valid input. So better make it `{1,2}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^[0-9]{1,5}([.,][0-9]{0,2})?$
```

[**Regex Demo**](http://rubular.com/r/A5bF9uL7yN)

Comment: No need to escape either `,` or `.` in the character class.